# How to avoid Linux becoming unresponsive if network is down

Tags: linux, networking

When a network drive for some reason becomes unavailable (or the entire network is down) Linux usually becomes unresponsive for several minutes (or tens of minutes). It's not related to a specific distro - for example it happened just a few minutes ago when my router was accidentally switched off, on both my Linux Mint 17 Desktop and my Raspberry Pi.

In both cases I had to reboot because it just hang.

I guess there must be some timeout setting to control how long the network should wait for connections.

This has bugged me for years and now I hope to find a solution :)

Comment: we speak about a fixed address or DHCP?

Comment: Try adjusting the TCP keepalive

Comment: @FranciscoTapia: Fixed address

Comment: try `allow-hotplug eth0` i.e in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: `allow-hotplug eth0` didn't help. I think it's actually NFS that doesn't like to get disconnected. The problem arises as soon as I try to access a network drive.